# Detect type of 802.11 on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios7, wifi

I found a way to determine data network type of iPhone but I need more information on if the device is connected via Wifi.
How can I find out which type of 802.11 (a/b/g/n) my iPhone is connected using xcode?

Comment: given xcode is an IDE only - not at all ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for that in the IOS SDK